# Calculation of Shortest Paths in a Directed Graph takes much longer than calculating Betweenness Centrality

Tags: python, matlab, graph-theory, igraph, directed-graph

First of all, I am trying to calculate the Betweenness Centrality of a fully connected directional graph with edge weights with N=3015 nodes. Matlab can do this in about 30 seconds and Python igraph can do it in a minute while Networkx takes hours as it is written in python and so I have abandoned it.

Second, I need to get a list of all of the shortest paths (those that minimize weights along path) between all pairs of nodes. In matlab there is a function to do this called **shortest path**. There is also a similar function in igraph called **get_shortest_paths**. I can only get one path back from each call.

So I loop over all $N^2$ pairs of nodes and extract the shortest path, store it in an array and then continue.

The problem is that while I can get betweenness centrality in under a minute, extracting all of the shortest paths takes hours in both matlab and igraph.

This seems strange given that betweenness centrality is based on the calculation of all of the shortest paths. So why does the extraction of the shortest paths take so much longer ?

Comment: The time needed to find the shortest paths from one node to all the other nodes is about the same as finding the shortest path to one other node. So you’re doing about N times too much computation.

Comment: Both [`shortestpathtree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpathtree.html) in MATLAB and [`get_shortest_paths`](https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/api/igraph.GraphBase.html#get_shortest_paths) in igraph allow you to specify a list of target nodes given a single source node which, as @Cris notes, shouldn't take significantly more time to compute for all target nodes than it does for a single target node. You would, of course, have to call either n times. I do find it curious that neither seems to have included a function to calculate all-pairs shortest paths.

Comment: Just to reply to the beginning of the post (*"I am trying to calculate the Betweenness Centrality..."*), if I can recommend you could look into `graph-tool` for Python network computations. It's also based on C++ but a few times faster than igraph, see [here](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance). Commonly used among network scientists except if you are using Windows on which it's a pain to install. It's also a few times faster on shortest paths than igraph too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the function [`get_all_shortest_paths`](https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/api/igraph.GraphBase.html#get_all_shortest_paths) instead of `get_shortest_path`. Indeed, `get_shortest_path` returns only one shortest path, but `get_all_shortest_paths` will return all shortest paths.

Answer (score 1):

The computation of all shortest paths as the independent application of the single-shortest-path algorithm for all points is not very efficient.

You can imagine that if the shortest paths from points A and B to another point C largely overlap, there must be a way to reuse the knowledge of building the path from A to C for quickly finding the path of B to C. In essence, that is the difference between algorithms such as [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (for single-source shortest paths) and others like the  [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) (for all shortest paths) [in igraph](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_distances_floyd_warshall), [in networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall_numpy.html) and in matlab I think it's [distances](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html) (which uses Johnson's algorithm, designed for sparse graphs - rather than the dense graphs you describe).